# Updating large database from Craft 2 > 3 via command line

Tags: craft3, updates

I'm migrating a large Craft + Commerce site up to Craft 3. I've completed all the initial steps and get as far as the "*To complete the update, some changes must be made to your database. Finish up*" message.

The first time I tried this it timed out, so I used the `./craft migrate/all` to perform all the database updates. This worked well - not surprised it timed out over http given the amount it has to do!

Problem is when going back to the Admin URL I still get the database message, if I click *Finish up* it still times out, I guess it is trying to reapply the migration.

Is there a way to let the Craft install know I have already done this?

Thanks

Comment: "Problem is when going back to the Admin URL I still get the database message," - that shouldn't have happened. Maybe your site was still in maintenance mode from the initial update attempt failure and after you ran the console command, the CP wanted to take it out of maintenance mode, Craft tried to make a database backup and it timed out before that could complete?

Answer (score 2):

Turns out the Craft needed to run another set of migrations for Commerce, so I ran the `./craft migrate/all` a couple more times to fully update the database.

If anyone is doing this, it's worth backing up the DB after each set of migrations to save running them again if you run into an error.